# Use Collections.frequency with a List<SomeBeanType>

Tags: java, list, hashset

I have a List of some bean type (Products) and I need to find what products from my list are repeated, lets say my bean Products contains getters and setters like these

```
public class Product {
 private int id;
 private String name;
 private BigDecimal cost;
 private int uniqueAssignedId;

 public Product(int id, String name, BigDecimal cost, int uniqueAssignedId) {
  this.id = id.....
 }

 public int getId() {
  return this.id;
 }

//The rest of getters and setters.
```

I'm trying to put this list into a map to find repeated "id" values, but it isn't working as I expected, the problem is that my list is a list(sorry for the redundancy) of sold products so every sold product has a unique uniqueAssignedId therefore the Objects are always differents, assuming my list is filled as follows:

```
listProducts.add(5, "Soda", 1.00, 1);
listProducts.add(3,"Phone", 300.00, 2);
listProducts.add(4, "Cofee", 5.00, 3);
listProducts.add(5, "Soda", 1.00, 4);
listProducts.add(4, "Cofee", 5.00, 5);
listProducts.add(5, "Soda", 1.00, 6);
```

(I know I would have to create an object Product product = new Product() and fill it with the setters and then add the object to my list, but this is simpler)

What I have tried as far:

```
Set<Product> uniqueId = new HashSet<Product>(listProducts);
        for (Product product : uniqueId) {
            System.out.println("The product with id "+product.getId+" was repeated: "
                    + Collections.frequency(listProducts, product.getId));
        }
```

But it always iterates 6 times instead of 3 times (3 is the number of differents products I sold). So How can I make the Hashset get only differents id? Should I use maps? Any clue will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you overridden `equals` and `hashcode` methods in your `Product` class?

Comment: I haven't tried because I don't really know how to do it, I have read about how override methods but I don't get it at all.

Comment: Nevermind when I created the my Bean, Netbeans automatically overrided the equals and hashcode, but as I told you I don't know what to do with it :/

Comment: IMO, adding `uniqueAssignedId` to the `Product` is not good design-wise. And it doesn't make sense to base the `Product`s `equals` and `hashCode` methods on that field. You might want to create another class `SoldProduct` with `uniqueAssignedId` and `product` fields. And it's equals and hashCode can be based on that id field.

Comment: Post your equals and hashcode methods.  If they include the uniqueAssignedId in the comparison, then two products will never be equal.

Comment: Actually the hashcode method includes the uniqueAssignedId, I tried to override the method with id but I failed, so I redisgn my algorithm again and I found other way to do it, takes more lines to execute what I want but at least works and don't waste much time as one could think. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public class ProductComparator implements Comparator<Product>
  {
     public int compare(Product p1, Product p2)
     {
          return p1.id-p2.id;
     }
  }


  ArrayList<Product> listProducts = new ArrayList<Product>();
  listProducts.add(new Product(5, "Soda", 1.00, 1));
  listProducts.add(new Product(3,"Phone", 300.00, 2));
  listProducts.add(new Product(4, "Cofee", 5.00, 3));
  listProducts.add(new Product(5, "Soda", 1.00, 4));
  listProducts.add(new Product(4, "Cofee", 5.00, 5));
  listProducts.add(new Product(5, "Soda", 1.00, 6));
  System.out.println(listProducts.size()); // Total records 

  TreeSet<Product> products = new TreeSet<Product>(new ProductComparator());
  products.addAll(listProducts);                
  ArrayList<Product> duplicate = new ArrayList<Product>();
  duplicate.addAll(products);
  listProducts.removeAll(duplicate);
  System.out.println(products.size()); // Now no duplicates in this set. 
  System.out.println(listProducts.size()); // Now only duplicate in this list
```

Comment: Thanks but what I was trying to do is to count the repeatd elements with Collections.frequency, not to delet them.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use **Comparable interface or Comparator** For sorting the List.

> Comparator in Java compare two objects provided, while Comparable
>   interface compares "this" reference with the object specified.
>
> Comparable in Java is used to implement natural ordering of object. In
>   Java API String, Date and wrapper classes implements Comparable
>   interface.

It will return a sorted List according to the count. It is Possible to do the sorting and retrieve the count from that using simple Programming.

**Refer [Comparable interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). Look [Here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/) for examples.**